# Bootstrap show different modal if a keyboard key is held down whilst button is pressed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

This might be a long shot and not possible but I had the idea and thought I'd ask.

I am using Bootstrap and have the below button which shows a login modal for users.

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal">
    Login
  </button>
</div>
```

Is it possible that if a keyboard key is held down whilst this button is pressed then it would show another modal, for example `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AdminModal">`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with JavaScript.  Don't use `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal"` because that's for the default case and in this scenario we'll want to roll our own.

You can have a regular button trigger like this:

```html
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="launchModal">
    Launch demo modal 
</button>
```

Then tap into the `click` event for it.  The jQuery event object will expose the current keypress at the time of the event.  Use those to choose whatever modal you would like.

```js
$("#launchModal").click(function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        $('#ctrlModal').modal('show');

    } else if (e.altKey) {
        $('#altModal').modal('show');

    } else if (e.shiftKey) {
        $('#shiftModal').modal('show');

    } else {
        $('#regModal').modal('show');
    }    
});
```

Then just setup whatever modals you'd like to open

### [Working Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/d0dopee2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to do the key handling. Here is an example:

```
$(document).bind('keypress', function(e){
    switch(e.keyCode)
    {
        case 37:
          //do something
        break;
    case 39:
         // do something
        break;
    case 80:
         // do something
        break;
    }
});
```

There are specifics to this as well (some keys wont auto repeat).

If a key is held down long enough it typically auto-repeats, and some additional events will be triggered on each autorepeat. On Macintosh and Linux systems, modifier keys usually don't auto-repeat, but on Windows systems they do (which seems weird to me). In most browsers, an autorepeat is sensibly treated as a character event, but not a key event, so it triggers a keypress but not a keydown or keyup. But, of course, there is some variation and exceptions.